Unable to display video created through cv2 in colab
I am trying to create a video from an image, But the video is not getting displayed in google colab. But the same video, when I download and play it in my local machine, It is working fine. I have provided a code to reproduce the above,
import numpy as np
import cv2
from IPython.display import Video, display

def create_random_image(width=256, height=256):
    return np.random.randint(0, 256, (height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

def modify_image_randomly(image):
    # Select random points and change pixel values
    for _ in range(100):  # Modify 100 random pixels
        x = np.random.randint(0, image.shape[1])
        y = np.random.randint(0, image.shape[0])
        image[y, x] = [np.random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)]
    return image

initial_image = create_random_image()

frame_width = initial_image.shape[1]
frame_height = initial_image.shape[0]
fps = 10
num_frames = 50  # Number of frames in the video

# Create a VideoWriter object to save as MP4
out = cv2.VideoWriter('random_video.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

# Generate frames and write to video
for i in range(num_frames):
    modified_image = modify_image_randomly(initial_image.copy())  # Modify a copy of the initial image
    out.write(modified_image)

# Release the video writer
out.release()

# Display the video in Colab
display(Video("random_video.mp4", embed=True))


